# Laravel ajax doesn't return data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create a post using ajax in Laravel. Ajax apparently works, but when calling the controller, it doesn't have any data.

```
url: $(this).data("route"),
```

Has an URL and works perfectly.

```
var opciones = $("[name=cargaYDescarga]").bootstrapSwitch('state');
```

Returns false or true. I think there's not a problem with this data type. I need to return this data to the controller and do a SQL or other.

```
$('[data-click="state"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function () {
        var opciones = $("[name=cargaYDescarga]").bootstrapSwitch('state');
        console.log(opciones);
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: $(this).data("route"),
            type: 'POST',
            data: {opcion: opciones}
        })
    });

    //Controller

    public function opcion(Request $request)
      {
         dd($request->input('opcion'));
      }
```

So, the question is: Do I have an error in this code? Ajax can´t pass true/false directly and I need to convert into a string?

Comment: are you using any middleware?

Comment: Nope. Only 'Route::match(['get', 'post'],'cargas/descargas/opcion', 'CargasYDescargasController@opcion');'

Comment: try return response()->json($request->input('opcion'),200); instead of dd($request->input('opcion'));

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the text opcion in the ajax in my case need to be 'opcion'. See the code.

```
$('[data-click="state"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function () {
            var opciones = $("[name=cargaYDescarga]").bootstrapSwitch('state');
            console.log(opciones);
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: $(this).data("route"),
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'opcion': opciones}
            })
        });
```